# Map function not returning all the arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, arrays, dictionary

So here I am trying to map through multiple arrays, and return all the data related to it. But only the first array is getting returned.
The strange thing here is that when I try console logging the same its working just fine. but the moment I put it inside any HTML tag the problem is coming up. What is wrong here? Any kinda help will be very useful.

```
function getHoveredEventDetails() {
  const formattedDay = day.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
  const matchingDates = [];

  eventsCountandDate.forEach((event) => {
    if (event.date === formattedDay) {
      matchingDates.push(event);
    }
  });
  let countKey = 1010;
  if (matchingDates.length > 0) {
    return matchingDates.map((event, index) => {
      const coursesDetails = event.courses;
      countKey = countKey + 1;
      return coursesDetails.map((course, courseIndex) => {
        return (
          <div className="eventDetails" key={`${index}-${courseIndex}`}>
            <div className="profile">
              <h1 className="profile_title">{course.courseName}</h1>
              <p className="profile_para">
                On {course.startProgramDates} till {course.endProgramDates},
                From {course.startTime} to {course.endTime}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the API data, which I am trying to get.

```
courseCount: 3, courses: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}], date:"14-02-2024"
```

Further If I expland the courses array then

```
courses: Array(3)
1:{courseName: 'Course 1', startProgramDates: '14-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', endTime: '13:00 PM ET'}
1:{courseName: 'Course 2', startProgramDates: '12-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '11:00 AM ET', endTime: '12:00 AM ET'}
2:{courseName: 'Course 3', startProgramDates: '13-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '10:00 PM ET', endTime: '11:00 AM ET'}
```

Comment: Where are you doing the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get all the 3 arrays printed on the dom with the same code.

Could you confirm your comparison is still returning multiple arrays?

```
const TestComponent: React.FC = () => {
function getHoveredEventDetails() {
    const formattedDay = "14-02-2024";
    const matchingDates: typeof apiData[0][] = [];

    apiData.forEach((event) => {
        if (event.date === formattedDay) {
            matchingDates.push(event);
        }
    });
    console.log({matchingDates});
    let countKey = 1010;
    if (matchingDates.length > 0) {
        return matchingDates.map((event, index) => {
            const coursesDetails = event.courses;
            countKey = countKey + 1;
            return coursesDetails.map((course, courseIndex) => {
                return (
                    <div className="eventDetails" key={`${index}-${courseIndex}`}>
                        <div className="profile">
                            <h1 className="profile_title">{course.courseName}</h1>
                            <p className="profile_para">
                                On {course.startProgramDates} till {course.endProgramDates},
                                From {course.startTime} to {course.endTime}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            });
        });
    }
}

return (
    <div>
        {getHoveredEventDetails()}
    </div>
)
}
```

I have used the below data to mock your API data.

```
const apiData = [{
courseCount: 3,
courses: [
    { courseName: 'Course 1', startProgramDates: '14-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', endTime: '13:00 PM ET' },
    { courseName: 'Course 2', startProgramDates: '12-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '11:00 AM ET', endTime: '12:00 AM ET' },
    { courseName: 'Course 3', startProgramDates: '13-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '10:00 PM ET', endTime: '11:00 AM ET' }],
date: "14-02-2024"
},
{
    courseCount: 2,
    courses: [
        { courseName: 'Course 4', startProgramDates: '14-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', endTime: '13:00 PM ET' },
        { courseName: 'Course 5', startProgramDates: '12-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '11:00 AM ET', endTime: '12:00 AM ET' }],
    date: "14-02-2024"
},
{
    courseCount: 2,
    courses: [
        { courseName: 'Course 6', startProgramDates: '14-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', endTime: '13:00 PM ET' },
        { courseName: 'Course 7', startProgramDates: '12-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '11:00 AM ET', endTime: '12:00 AM ET' }],
    date: "14-02-2024"
},
]
```

And the dom looks like below.
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an array-of-arrays. You're not telling us what it is you exactly want to return, but given you've tagged react.js, presumably a flat list of divs; in that case, use `flatMap`:

```
return matchingDates.flatMap((event, index) => {
   ...
```

Your component further simplifies to something like

```
function getHoveredEventDetails() {
  const formattedDay = day.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
  const matchingDates = eventsCountandDate.filter(
    (event) => event.date === formattedDay,
  );
  return matchingDates.flatMap((event, dateIndex) =>
    event.courses.map((course, courseIndex) => (
      <div className="eventDetails" key={`${dateIndex}-${courseIndex}`}>
        <div className="profile">
          <h1 className="profile_title">{course.courseName}</h1>
          <p className="profile_para">
            On {course.startProgramDates} till {course.endProgramDates}, From{" "}
            {course.startTime} to {course.endTime}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )),
  );
}
```

Comment: In 'matchingDates', there are lets say 3 arrays and it contains few data. Which I want to show in the webpage(Thats why I have put them under html tags) 
But problem here is that the above code is not returing all the 3 arrays, instead just the one. 

But if i console log those data, i could see the 3 arrays getting returned, but not while I put it under some html tag. I dont understand this behavior

Comment: An array of arrays isn't valid React children. Did you try this approach? Did it not work?

Comment: @AKX An array of arrays is valid, it gets flattened out.

Comment: @NickParsons So it would seem. I stand corrected!

Answer (score 0):

I think It is weird. Mybe it might works:

```
function getHoveredEventDetails() {
  const formattedDay = day.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
  const matchingDates = [];

  eventsCountandDate.forEach((event) => {
    if (event.date === formattedDay) {
      matchingDates.push(event);
    }
  });
  let countKey = 1010;
  if (matchingDates.length > 0) {
     matchingDates.forEach((event, index) => {
      const coursesDetails = event.courses;
      countKey = countKey + 1;
      coursesDetails.forEach((course, courseIndex) => {
        return (
          <div className="eventDetails" key={`${index}-${courseIndex}`}>
            <div className="profile">
              <h1 className="profile_title">{course.courseName}</h1>
              <p className="profile_para">
                On {course.startProgramDates} till {course.endProgramDates},
                From {course.startTime} to {course.endTime}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Its working the same way as earlier, no change